# Conditional expectation for coin toss

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly and let T be the number of tosses before two consecutive tails occur for the first time.

Show that
E(T | the first toss resulted in tail) = 2 + ½E(T)

Well T will have geometric distribution but some how I can't find the answer. Please help.

Comment: Is your question how to prove that statement, how to find the expectation with a geometric series, or are you asking the connection between the two approaches? Using that recurrence will be equivalent to using a geometric series.

Comment: Yes my question is about proving the statement

Comment: The statement E( T | first toss resulted in tail) = 2 + ½E(T)

Answer (score 1):

Half the time, the second toss is tails, so it takes $2$ tosses.  The other half the time it's heads, so we've done $2$ tosses and we're back where we started.  $$E(T|\text{first toss tails})=\frac12\cdot2+\frac12(2+E(T))$$

Comment: Please elaborate this. I can't understand this.

Comment: @SoumajitDas What part don't you understand?

Comment: What does "half the time the second toss is tail so it take two tosses" mean ?

Comment: @SoumajitDas If the second toss is tails, we've had two consecutive tails, so the game is over in two tosses.

Comment: and what does the other line mean when head occurs and why do we have to start over again ?

Comment: @SoumajitDas If the second toss is heads, there have been two tosses,  and no consecutive tails, so you're back in  the initial position.  For now on, it will take an average of $E(T)$ tosses to get two consecutive tails.

Comment: Had been my question E( T | first toss resulted in head ), then would the answer be  1 + E(T) ? I am just asking out of curiosity as I was trying this too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the first toss is T, we have

- TT with probability $\frac{1}{2}$
- THTT that is the first goal (4 tosses) if the second is H, that is $T+2$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Concluding, we can rewrtite our contitional random variable in the following way

$$ (T|\text{First toss is tail}) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \frac{1}{2} \\
T+2, & \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$

With expectation as showed before and according to your statement

Comment: Had been my question E( T | first toss resulted in head ), then would the answer be  1 + E(T) ? I am just asking out of curiosity as I was trying this too.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.